# How can i make the list items as three in a row

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I recently purchased this theme. I want to customize the theme file with displaying the items in homepage i.e., List of post Appear is four and i want to do is three in a row. Is it possible to do this using css or jquery.
Here is the link of theme
In a homepage you can see the post as four (I want it to be three)
**[Here is the link](http://themetastic.com/buddypress/?wptheme=Network)**

Is it possible using css to make the list as three?

Comment: Try increasing the `width` for `.articles li` to something around `290px` roughly.

Comment: Thanks @Harry This works great How can i make the image as center in the div? Can you assist me please

Comment: I have not tried it mate. But check if adding `margin: 0px auto;` to `.articles .thumb` helps. If yes, I will add both as an answer. I am facing some issues with my browser console :(

Comment: Yes harry it works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Item 1:** To limit the number of blocks displayed per line, increase the width of each item like below:

```
.articles li {
    padding: 7px;
    width: 30%; /*This can be in px also. If in px give a value roughly above 290px. */
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    min-height: 210px;
    margin: 0 3px 5px 1px;
}
```

**Item 2:** To center the image within each block, add `margin` like below:

```
.articles .thumb {
    width: 228px;
    height: 108px;
    margin: 0px auto; /*added this line to center image horizontally.*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a change to your CSS class to achieve this.

**For Instance,**

```
.articles li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3px 5px 1px;
    min-height: 210px;
    padding: 7px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 310px; /* This has to be increased */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A modern method could be:

```
.articles li {
  padding: 7px;
  width: 308px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  min-height: 210px;
  margin: 0 9px 9px 0;
}
.articles li:nth-child(3n) {margin-right:0;}
```

Which will give you this:
[image: Result]

If you want to make it compatible with older browsers, use this small jQuery snippet:

```
$(".articles li:nth-child(3n)").css("margin-right", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try to add :

```
.articles li:nth-child(n) {
   margin-left: 30px;
   margin-right: 50px;
}
```

it's give you result like this:[image]